# how to code JavaScript for New window on clicking submit button displaying registration information with ok and Cancel?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want a pop up box containing information of username,email id etc. on clicking submit button and OK and Cancel button to confirm with JAVA SCRIPT. .how to code JavaScript for New window on clicking submit button displaying registration information with OK and Cancel.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (confirm("Press 'OK' to leave, or 'Cancel' if you want to stay: "))
    {         
       window.location="http://google.com";
    }
    else
    {         
      <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go back</a> 
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can do using [JQUERY UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)

you may want to check ModalForm in that

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Create an account": function() {
                    var bValid = true;
                    allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );


                    if ( bValid ) {
                        $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" + 
                            "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" + 
                            "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>" ); 
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() {
                allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
            }
        });
```